# setSrc not updating new audio (.mp3) in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, mediaelement.js

I am trying to load a new audio when an audio ends. This somehow doesn't work in FF.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('audio').mediaelementplayer({
            success: function(media, node, player) {
                media.addEventListener('ended', function(){
                    media.src = 'Audio/4typesslide9.mp3';
                    media.load();
                    media.play();
                }, false);
            }
        });
});
```

This works perfectly fine in Chrome. (I have not tested this in other browsers yet)

Please help me with this. I am stuck at this point for a loooong time...

This is the error I get:

> HTTP "Content-Type" of "audio/mpeg" is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in Firefox because Firefox does not play mp3's.
You'll need to add a `<source>` element with a .webm version